# C multiple data types passed to the same function

Tags: c, function, types, bit-manipulation

I have this function that **takes an int* as parameter and changes its nth bit to 1 or 0** :

```
void change_nth_bit(int *value, uint8_t bit, uint8_t n) {
    (*value) ^= (-bit ^ (*value)) & (1U << n);
}
```

Can I guarantee that it will work as value could be of type :

- ***uint8_t**
- ***char**
- ***uint16_t**

Or should I make a function for each data type ?

Comment: No you can't make a generic function that takes pointers to types of differing size. That ways lies madness (and undefined behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a single function for that, you need multiple functions.

Otherwise, accessing `(*value)` that is an integer pointer pointing to `uint8_t` object, i.e.

```
// This code is broken
unit8_t val = 0xC4;
change_nth_bit((int*)&val, 3, 1);
//             ^^^^^^
//               |
// Invalid ------+
```

would result in undefined behavior.

Note that if you put this code in a macro (after replacing a pointer with a macro parameter reference) you should be able to achieve the desired result without repeating your code:

```
#define CHANGE_NTH_BIT(v,b,n) (v) ^= (-(b) ^ (v)) & (1U << (n))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications ! So I could just write this macro and call it with any data type as if it was a function ?

Comment: @PaulLemarchand Yes. This is less safe than having a function, in the sense that `v` could be evaluated twice, but you would be able to call it with any data type.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand Yes. This is less safe than having a function, in the sense that `v` could be evaluated twice, but you would be able to call it with any data type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the pointer punning as safe (on most system it is) and little endian

```
void cnb(void *val, size_t bit, int value)
{
   uint8_t *ptr = val;

   ptr += bit >> 3;
   if(val) *ptr |= (!!val) << (bit & 7);
      else *ptr &= ~((!!val) << (bit & 7));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/HBEKme

Comment: Thanks, I already changed my code to a macro as suggested by @dasblinkenlight . Might look into this too though.

Comment: @Paul Lemarchand this "tricky" way of assigning the bit  is less efficient than "notmal" reset and set methot. It just looks smarter :) https://godbolt.org/g/2XFeGM

Comment: I see, there are indeed fewer assembly instructions. Thanks for the tip !